# Referenced libraries in Visual Studio 2010 projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-linking

Let's say I have a C++ Visual Studio 2010 solution with 2 projects: one *main project* with the program entry point and a second project with a *static library* (linked against the main one), that is used in other VS2010 solutions.

The *static library project* uses an additional third-party library (.lib). Currently, this third-party static library is set in the *main project's* Additional Dependencies field of the Linker -> Input section of the Property Pages, in order for the whole program to compile.

My question is, is there a way to add this dependency in the *static library project* itself, so I don't have to add it manually in each of the *main projects* from the different VS2010 solutions where the *static library project* is included?

Are there different ways to do this? Can I chose embed this third-party library in the .lib generated by the static library project? Is there any good practice or recommendations on doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think there's any way to do this with static linking I'm afraid..

Comment: Just add the .lib to the library project with Project + Add Existing item and it will get merged.  Having multiple copies of the same .lib isn't the greatest idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static library is just like any other output of the linker - you can add additional dependencies in the 'librarian options' of your static lib project and they will be linked in as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Your static library project uses a third party static library. You only need to link the library when you create your static library, and your static library dont have to ship the third part with it, but just your library. Your static library embeds all the required binary parts from the third party static library to your static library.

If you are not using any of stuff from the third party library (i.e. if your static library has the functionality for all other projects require ) in other projects then you dont have to link aganist the third party static library. Just use your static libray instead.